# Can worms delete your network?

Tags: network, malware, wifi

A few nights ago, our network wifi had somehow gotten deleted, resetting it to its default network name. Can a worm delete your network wifi? Not saying that is what happened but it was a thought that started running through my head.

Comment: What do you mean by *deleting the network*? If a system is infected with malware, it can usually do whatever a legitimate user can do on that system. If a user can reset network settings, malware could too.

Comment: Just updated my question.

Comment: What is a network name ? a SSID ? a Network interface controller name? Even with the update I still don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Baptiste it was the network wifi. The one that you connect to from your phone or computer without your cables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your SSID was reset to its default name, and you're asking if a Malware could be responsible.

Yes, it is possible. Searching on the web if your Router model is vulnerable will help you. Most of the makers patch those kinds of flaw by Making some new firmware version. Keeping the router firmware up to date is a good habit.

### Not in the question scope

If this WIFI Router is your ISP property, please call them. They may have scheduled a global factory reset for some reason. (Which is pretty rare)

Make sure you do not use WEP encryption. Exploiting a weak encryption scheme is one of the most popular ways for hijacking a WIFI network.

If you cannot figure out why your Wifi Router has been reset to its default configuration, it might have been compromised.